# Relative button

Tags: javascript, html, css

This quiz works on the computer, but when I try to use it on a Mobile phone the text is larger and condensed so the button stops working. I tried to change the .slide to relative and the .button top-margin to 30px, but the button stops working if the .slide is relative. So because that wasn't working I was trying to basically set the margin-top on the button large enough so it would always work.

Ideally the button is relative to the current question and appears about 30px below the answers. What am I doing wrong here? (Pertaining to the css, I know now my math was done very inefficiently.)

```html
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f8f6f0;
  }

  h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .section-description {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .question {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .answers {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .answers label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  button {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: #279;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

  button:hover {
    background-color: #38a;
  }

  .slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }

  .active-slide {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  .quiz-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
</style>
<h1>ASVAB PRETEST</h1>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="quiz-container">
  <div id="quiz">&nbsp;</div>
  
</div>

<p><button id="previous" type="button">Previous Question</button><button id="next" type="button">Next Question</button><button id="submit" type="button">Submit Quiz</button></p>

<div id="results">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="results">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="category-scores">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="raw-scores">&nbsp;</div>

<script>
  // variable for categories
  const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
  const categoryScoresContainer = document.getElementById('category-scores');
  const rawScoresContainer = document.getElementById('raw-scores');
  const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
  const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

  (function() {
    // Functions
    function buildQuiz() {

      // variable to store the HTML output
      const output = [];

      // for each question...
      myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

        // variable to store the list of possible answers
        const answers = [];

        // and for each available answer...
        for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
          // ...add an HTML radio button
          answers.push(
            `<label>
              <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
              ${letter} :
              ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
            </label>`
          );
        }

        // add this question and its answers to the output
        output.push(
          `<div class="slide">
            ${currentQuestion.description ? `<div class="section-description">${currentQuestion.description}</div>` : ''}
            <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
            <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
          </div>`
        );
      });

      // combine output list into one string of HTML and put it on the page
      quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");
      const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
      nextButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const description = document.getElementById("description");
        if (description) quizContainer.removeChild(description);
      });
    }

    function showResults() {

      // gather answer containers from our quiz
      const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');

      // keep track of user's answers
      let numCorrect = 0;

      // for each question...
      myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

        // find selected answer
        const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
        const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
        const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;

        // if answer is correct
        if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
          // add to the number of correct answers
          numCorrect++;
          scores[currentQuestion.category]++;

          //multiplies by 2 for final result
          scores[currentQuestion.category]++;

        }
      });

      //hide myQuestions
      quizContainer.innerHTML = "";

      //calculate VE
      let ve = scores.wk + scores.pc;
      let finalve;
      if (ve === 0) {
        finalve = 20;
      } else if (ve === 2) {
        finalve = 40;
      } else if (ve === 4) {
        finalve = 42;
      } else if (ve === 6) {
        finalve = 46;
      } else if (ve === 8) {
        finalve = 50;
      } else if (ve === 10) {
        finalve = 54;
      } else if (ve === 12) {
        finalve = 56;
      } else if (ve === 14) {
        finalve = 60;
      } else if (ve === 16) {
        finalve = 64;
      } else if (ve === 18) {
        finalve = 66;
      } else if (ve === 20) {
        finalve = 70;
      } else if (ve === 22) {
        finalve = 74;
      } else if (ve === 24) {
        finalve = 78;
      } else if (ve === 26) {
        finalve = 80;
      } else if (ve === 28) {
        finalve = 84;
      } else if (ve === 30) {
        finalve = 88;
      } else if (ve === 32) {
        finalve = 90;
      } else if (ve === 34) {
        finalve = 94;
      } else if (ve === 36) {
        finalve = 98;
      } else if (ve === 38) {
        finalve = 100;
      } else if (ve === 40) {
        finalve = 104;
      } else if (ve === 42) {
        finalve = 108;
      } else if (ve === 44) {
        finalve = 112;
      } else if (ve === 46) {
        finalve = 114;
      } else if (ve === 48) {
        finalve = 118;
      } else if (ve === 50) {
        finalve = 122;
      } else if (ve === 52) {
        finalve = 122;
      } else {
        // Handle any other cases
      }

      //calculate ar
      let ar = scores.ar;
      let finalar;
      if (ar === 0) {
        finalar = 26;
      } else if (ar === 2) {
        finalar = 27;
      } else if (ar === 4) {
        finalar = 30;
      } else if (ar === 6) {
        finalar = 32;
      } else if (ar === 8) {
        finalar = 35;
      } else if (ar === 10) {
        finalar = 38;
      } else if (ar === 12) {
        finalar = 41;
      } else if (ar === 14) {
        finalar = 44;
      } else if (ar === 16) {
        finalar = 47;
      } else if (ar === 18) {
        finalar = 49;
      } else if (ar === 20) {
        finalar = 52;
      } else if (ar === 22) {
        finalar = 55;
      } else if (ar === 24) {
        finalar = 58;
      } else if (ar === 26) {
        finalar = 61;
      } else if (ar === 28) {
        finalar = 63;
      } else if (ar === 30) {
        finalar = 66;
      } else {
        // Handle any other cases
      }

      let mk = scores.mk;
      let finalmk;
      if (mk === 0) {
        finalmk = 29;
      } else if (mk === 2) {
        finalmk = 31;
      } else if (mk === 4) {
        finalmk = 34;
      } else if (mk === 6) {
        finalmk = 37;
      } else if (mk === 8) {
        finalmk = 41;
      } else if (mk === 10) {
        finalmk = 44;
      } else if (mk === 12) {
        finalmk = 47;
      } else if (mk === 14) {
        finalmk = 50;
      } else if (mk === 16) {
        finalmk = 53;
      } else if (mk === 18) {
        finalmk = 57;
      } else if (mk === 20) {
        finalmk = 60;
      } else if (mk === 22) {
        finalmk = 63;
      } else if (mk === 24) {
        finalmk = 66;
      } else if (mk === 26) {
        finalmk = 88;
      } else {
        // Handle any other cases
      }

      //calculates std
      let std = finalve + finalar + finalmk;

      //converts std to pct
      let pct;
      if (std >= 80 && std <= 120) {
        pct = 1;
      } else if (std >= 121 && std <= 124) {
        pct = 2;
      } else if (std >= 125 && std <= 127) {
        pct = 3;
      } else if (std >= 128 && std <= 131) {
        pct = 4;
      } else if (std >= 132 && std <= 134) {
        pct = 5;
      } else if (std >= 135 && std <= 137) {
        pct = 6;
      } else if (std >= 138 && std <= 139) {
        pct = 7;
      } else if (std >= 140 && std <= 142) {
        pct = 8;
      } else if (std >= 143 && std <= 144) {
        pct = 9;
      } else if (std >= 145 && std <= 146) {
        pct = 10;
      } else if (std >= 147 && std <= 148) {
        pct = 11;
      } else if (std >= 149 && std <= 150) {
        pct = 12;
      } else if (std >= 151 && std <= 153) {
        pct = 13;
      } else if (std === 154) {
        pct = 14;
      } else if (std >= 155 && std <= 156) {
        pct = 15;
      } else if (std >= 157 && std <= 158) {
        pct = 16;
      } else if (std >= 159 && std <= 160) {
        pct = 17;
      } else if (std >= 161 && std <= 162) {
        pct = 18;
      } else if (std >= 163 && std <= 164) {
        pct = 19;
      } else if (std === 165) {
        pct = 20;
      } else if (std >= 166 && std <= 167) {
        pct = 21;
      } else if (std >= 168 && std <= 169) {
        pct = 22;
      } else if (std >= 170 && std <= 171) {
        pct = 23;
      } else if (std === 172) {
        pct = 24;
      } else if (std === 173) {
        pct = 25;
      } else if (std >= 174 && std <= 175) {
        pct = 26;
      } else if (std >= 176 && std <= 177) {
        pct = 27;
      } else if (std === 178) {
        pct = 28;
      } else if (std === 179) {
        pct = 29;
      } else if (std === 181) {
        pct = 30;
      } else if (std === 182) {
        pct = 31;
      } else if (std >= 183 && std <= 184) {
        pct = 32;
      } else if (std === 185) {
        pct = 33;
      } else if (std === 186) {
        pct = 34;
      } else if (std >= 187 && std <= 188) {
        pct = 35;
      } else if (std === 189) {
        pct = 36;
      } else if (std === 190) {
        pct = 37;
      } else if (std === 191) {
        pct = 38;
      } else if (std === 192) {
        pct = 39;
      } else if (std === 193) {
        pct = 40;
      } else if (std === 194) {
        pct = 41;
      } else if (std >= 195 && std <= 196) {
        pct = 42;
      } else if (std === 197) {
        pct = 43;
      } else if (std === 198) {
        pct = 44;
      } else if (std === 199) {
        pct = 45;
      } else if (std === 200) {
        pct = 46;
      } else if (std === 201) {
        pct = 47;
      } else if (std === 202) {
        pct = 48;
      } else if (std === 203) {
        pct = 49;
      } else if (std === 204) {
        pct = 50;
      } else if (std === 205) {
        pct = 51;
      } else if (std === 206) {
        pct = 52;
      } else if (std >= 207 && std <= 208) {
        pct = 53;
      } else if (std === 209) {
        pct = 54;
      } else if (std === 210) {
        pct = 55;
      } else if (std === 211) {
        pct = 56;
      } else if (std === 212) {
        pct = 57;
      } else if (std === 213) {
        pct = 58;
      } else if (std === 214) {
        pct = 60;
      } else if (std === 215) {
        pct = 61;
      } else if (std === 216) {
        pct = 62;
      } else if (std === 217) {
        pct = 63;
      } else if (std === 218) {
        pct = 64;
      } else if (std === 219) {
        pct = 65;
      } else if (std === 220) {
        pct = 66;
      } else if (std === 221) {
        pct = 67;
      } else if (std === 222) {
        pct = 68;
      } else if (std === 223) {
        pct = 69;
      } else if (std === 224) {
        pct = 70;
      } else if (std === 225) {
        pct = 71;
      } else if (std === 226) {
        pct = 72;
      } else if (std === 227) {
        pct = 73;
      } else if (std === 228) {
        pct = 74;
      } else if (std === 229) {
        pct = 75;
      } else if (std === 230) {
        pct = 76;
      } else if (std === 231) {
        pct = 77;
      } else if (std === 232) {
        pct = 78;
      } else if (std === 233) {
        pct = 79;
      } else if (std >= 234 && std <= 235) {
        pct = 80;
      } else if (std === 236) {
        pct = 81;
      } else if (std === 237) {
        pct = 82;
      } else if (std === 238) {
        pct = 83;
      } else if (std === 239) {
        pct = 84;
      } else if (std === 240) {
        pct = 85;
      } else if (std === 241) {
        pct = 86;
      } else if (std === 242) {
        pct = 87;
      } else if (std === 243) {
        pct = 88;
      } else if (std === 244) {
        pct = 89;
      } else if (std === 245) {
        pct = 90;
      } else if (std === 246) {
        pct = 91;
      } else if (std === 247) {
        pct = 92;
      } else if (std === 248) {
        pct = 93;
      } else if (std === 249) {
        pct = 94;
      } else if (std === 250) {
        pct = 95;
      } else if (std === 251) {
        pct = 96;
      } else if (std === 252) {
        pct = 97;
      } else if (std === 253) {
        pct = 98;
      } else if (std >= 254 && std <= 320) {
        pct = 99;
      } else {
        // Handle any other cases
      }
      // show number of correct answers out of total
      resultsContainer.innerHTML = `${numCorrect} out of ${myQuestions.length}`;
      categoryScoresContainer.innerHTML = `
      <p>
        <b>Screenshot this page and send it to your recruiter.</b>
        </p>
            <p>Your estimated AFQT score is ${pct}</p><br /><br />
            <p>Word Knowledge = ${scores.wk/2} out of 18</p>
            <p>Arithmetic Reasoning = ${scores.ar/2} out of 15</p>
            <p>Paragraph Comprehension = ${scores.pc/2} out of 8</p>
            <p>Mathmematics Knowledge = ${scores.mk/2} out of 13</p>`;

      // hide previous, next and submit button, and make quiz read-only
      const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
      const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
      const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
      previousButton.style.display = "none";
      nextButton.style.display = "none";
      submitButton.style.display = "none";

      const inputElements = quizContainer.querySelectorAll("input");
      inputElements.forEach(input => {
        input.setAttribute("disabled", true);


      });

      //add restart button
      const restartButton = document.getElementById("restart");
      restartButton.style.display = "block";
      restartButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        location.reload();
      });
    }

    function showSlide(n) {
      slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('active-slide');
      slides[n].classList.add('active-slide');
      currentSlide = n;
      if (currentSlide === 0) {
        previousButton.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        previousButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
      }
      if (currentSlide === slides.length - 1) {
        nextButton.style.display = 'none';
        submitButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
      } else {
        nextButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
        submitButton.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function showNextSlide() {
      showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
    }

    function showPreviousSlide() {
      showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
    }

    // Variables
    const quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
    const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
    const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
    const myQuestions = [{
        category: "wk",
        description: "<h2>PART I - WORD KNOWLEDGE. YOU WILL HAVE 7 MINUTES TO COMPLETE.</h2>",
        question: "1. <b><u>SMALL</u></b> MOST NEARLY MEANS?",
        answers: {
          a: "STURDY",
          b: "ROUND",
          c: "CHEAP",
          d: "LITTLE"
        },
        correctAnswer: "d"
      },
      {
        category: "ar",
        description: "<h2>PART II - ARITHMETIC REASONING - YOU WILL HAVE FOURTEEN (14) MINUTES:</h2>",
        question: "1. TWO AUTOMOBILES START TOGETHER FROM THE SAME PLACE AND TRAVEL ALONG THE SAME ROUTE. THE FIRST AVERAGES 40 MPH. THE SECOND 55 MPH. HOW MANY MILES FURTHER ALONG THE ROUTE IS THE SECOND AUTO AT THE END OF THE 5TH HOUR?",
        answers: {
          a: "55 x 5",
          b: "55 - 40",
          c: "(55x5) - (40x5)",
          d: "55/5 - 40/5"
        },
        correctAnswer: "c"
      },
      {
        category: "pc",
        description: "<h2>PART III - PARAGRAPH COMPREHENSION - YOU WILL HAVE SEVEN (7) MINUTES:</h2>",
        question: "1. THE DUTY OF THE LIGHTHOUSE KEEPER IS TO KEEP THE LIGHT BURNING NO MATTER WHAT HAPPENS, SO THAT SHIPS WILL BE WARNED OF THE PRESENCE OF DANGEROUS ROCKS. IF A SHIPWRECK SHOULD OCCUR NEAR THE LIGHTHOUSE, EVEN THOUGH HE WOULD LIKE TO AID IN THE RESCUE OF IT'S CREW AND PASSENGERS, THE LIGHTHOUSE KEEPER MUST......",
        answers: {
          a: "STAY AT HIS LIGHT",
          b: "RUSH TO THEIR AID",
          c: "TURN OUT THE LIGHT",
          d: "QUICKLY SOUND THE SIREN"
        },
        correctAnswer: "a"
      },
      {
        category: "mk",
        description: "<h2>PART IV - MATHEMATICS KNOWLEDGE - YOU WILL HAVE TWELVE (12) MINUTES:</h2>",
        question: "1. WHICH OF THE FOLLOWING IS THE SMALLEST PRIME NUMBER GREATER THAN 200?",
        answers: {
          a: "201",
          b: "205",
          c: "211",
          d: "214"
        },
        correctAnswer: "c"
      },
    ];

    // Kick things off
    buildQuiz();

    // Pagination
    const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
    const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    let currentSlide = 0;
    let scores = {
      wk: 0,
      ar: 0,
      pc: 0,
      mk: 0,
    };

    // Show the first slide
    showSlide(currentSlide);

    // Event listeners
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', showResults);
    previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
    nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: That's a LOT of code, provide a [mre] (emphasis on the minimal). Too much code makes it hard to pinpoint issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed three things about your code:

The first thing is I enabled the button to click, the solution is to add *z-index* into the CSS. Please notice that do not set the value as *99999* because it will be hard for you to maintain the website. For example, if you want to add something else that is above the button(such as login to take next question or something like that), you have to set new elements' z-index as *99999999*

The second thing I changed is changing *p* into *div* because you use buttons in *p* and that will not work in some cases.

The last thing is to let the ButtonDIV at the bottom by using *top:calc(100vh - 10px);* (Your requirement), and now it is at the bottom.

Here is the code:

```html
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #f8f6f0;
      }

      h1 {
        font-weight: 300;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .section-description {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .question {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .answers {
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .answers label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      button {
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
        background-color: #279;
        color: #fff;
        border: 0px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 350px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        z-index:100;
      }

      button:hover {
        background-color: #38a;
      }

      .slide {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.5s;
      }

      .active-slide {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
      }

      .quiz-container {
        position: relative;
        height: 200px;
        margin-top: 60px;
      }
      #BUTTONDIV{
        margin-bottom: 0;
        top:calc(100vh - 10px);
        height:300px;
        position:relative;
      }
    </style>
    <h1>ASVAB PRETEST</h1>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <div class="quiz-container">
      <div id="quiz">&nbsp;</div>
      
    </div>

    <div id="BUTTONDIV"><button id="previous" type="button">Previous Question</button><button id="next" type="button">Next Question</button><button id="submit" type="button">Submit Quiz</button></div>
    <!--Do not use p here, instead, you are suppoesed to use div-->

    <div id="results">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="results">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="category-scores">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="raw-scores">&nbsp;</div>

    <script>
      // variable for categories
      const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
      const categoryScoresContainer = document.getElementById('category-scores');
      const rawScoresContainer = document.getElementById('raw-scores');
      const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
      const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

      (function() {
        // Functions
        function buildQuiz() {

          // variable to store the HTML output
          const output = [];

          // for each question...
          myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

            // variable to store the list of possible answers
            const answers = [];

            // and for each available answer...
            for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
              // ...add an HTML radio button
              answers.push(
                `<label>
                  <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
                  ${letter} :
                  ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
                </label>`
              );
            }

            // add this question and its answers to the output
            output.push(
              `<div class="slide">
                ${currentQuestion.description ? `<div class="section-description">${currentQuestion.description}</div>` : ''}
                <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
                <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
              </div>`
            );
          });

          // combine output list into one string of HTML and put it on the page
          quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");
          const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
          nextButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const description = document.getElementById("description");
            if (description) quizContainer.removeChild(description);
          });
        }

        function showResults() {

          // gather answer containers from our quiz
          const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');

          // keep track of user's answers
          let numCorrect = 0;

          // for each question...
          myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

            // find selected answer
            const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
            const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
            const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;

            // if answer is correct
            if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
              // add to the number of correct answers
              numCorrect++;
              scores[currentQuestion.category]++;

              //multiplies by 2 for final result
              scores[currentQuestion.category]++;

            }
          });

          //hide myQuestions
          quizContainer.innerHTML = "";

          //calculate VE
          let ve = scores.wk + scores.pc;
          let finalve;
          if (ve === 0) {
            finalve = 20;
          } else if (ve === 2) {
            finalve = 40;
          } else if (ve === 4) {
            finalve = 42;
          } else if (ve === 6) {
            finalve = 46;
          } else if (ve === 8) {
            finalve = 50;
          } else if (ve === 10) {
            finalve = 54;
          } else if (ve === 12) {
            finalve = 56;
          } else if (ve === 14) {
            finalve = 60;
          } else if (ve === 16) {
            finalve = 64;
          } else if (ve === 18) {
            finalve = 66;
          } else if (ve === 20) {
            finalve = 70;
          } else if (ve === 22) {
            finalve = 74;
          } else if (ve === 24) {
            finalve = 78;
          } else if (ve === 26) {
            finalve = 80;
          } else if (ve === 28) {
            finalve = 84;
          } else if (ve === 30) {
            finalve = 88;
          } else if (ve === 32) {
            finalve = 90;
          } else if (ve === 34) {
            finalve = 94;
          } else if (ve === 36) {
            finalve = 98;
          } else if (ve === 38) {
            finalve = 100;
          } else if (ve === 40) {
            finalve = 104;
          } else if (ve === 42) {
            finalve = 108;
          } else if (ve === 44) {
            finalve = 112;
          } else if (ve === 46) {
            finalve = 114;
          } else if (ve === 48) {
            finalve = 118;
          } else if (ve === 50) {
            finalve = 122;
          } else if (ve === 52) {
            finalve = 122;
          } else {
            // Handle any other cases
          }

          //calculate ar
          let ar = scores.ar;
          let finalar;
          if (ar === 0) {
            finalar = 26;
          } else if (ar === 2) {
            finalar = 27;
          } else if (ar === 4) {
            finalar = 30;
          } else if (ar === 6) {
            finalar = 32;
          } else if (ar === 8) {
            finalar = 35;
          } else if (ar === 10) {
            finalar = 38;
          } else if (ar === 12) {
            finalar = 41;
          } else if (ar === 14) {
            finalar = 44;
          } else if (ar === 16) {
            finalar = 47;
          } else if (ar === 18) {
            finalar = 49;
          } else if (ar === 20) {
            finalar = 52;
          } else if (ar === 22) {
            finalar = 55;
          } else if (ar === 24) {
            finalar = 58;
          } else if (ar === 26) {
            finalar = 61;
          } else if (ar === 28) {
            finalar = 63;
          } else if (ar === 30) {
            finalar = 66;
          } else {
            // Handle any other cases
          }

          let mk = scores.mk;
          let finalmk;
          if (mk === 0) {
            finalmk = 29;
          } else if (mk === 2) {
            finalmk = 31;
          } else if (mk === 4) {
            finalmk = 34;
          } else if (mk === 6) {
            finalmk = 37;
          } else if (mk === 8) {
            finalmk = 41;
          } else if (mk === 10) {
            finalmk = 44;
          } else if (mk === 12) {
            finalmk = 47;
          } else if (mk === 14) {
            finalmk = 50;
          } else if (mk === 16) {
            finalmk = 53;
          } else if (mk === 18) {
            finalmk = 57;
          } else if (mk === 20) {
            finalmk = 60;
          } else if (mk === 22) {
            finalmk = 63;
          } else if (mk === 24) {
            finalmk = 66;
          } else if (mk === 26) {
            finalmk = 88;
          } else {
            // Handle any other cases
          }

          //calculates std
          let std = finalve + finalar + finalmk;

          //converts std to pct
          let pct;
          if (std >= 80 && std <= 120) {
            pct = 1;
          } else if (std >= 121 && std <= 124) {
            pct = 2;
          } else if (std >= 125 && std <= 127) {
            pct = 3;
          } else if (std >= 128 && std <= 131) {
            pct = 4;
          } else if (std >= 132 && std <= 134) {
            pct = 5;
          } else if (std >= 135 && std <= 137) {
            pct = 6;
          } else if (std >= 138 && std <= 139) {
            pct = 7;
          } else if (std >= 140 && std <= 142) {
            pct = 8;
          } else if (std >= 143 && std <= 144) {
            pct = 9;
          } else if (std >= 145 && std <= 146) {
            pct = 10;
          } else if (std >= 147 && std <= 148) {
            pct = 11;
          } else if (std >= 149 && std <= 150) {
            pct = 12;
          } else if (std >= 151 && std <= 153) {
            pct = 13;
          } else if (std === 154) {
            pct = 14;
          } else if (std >= 155 && std <= 156) {
            pct = 15;
          } else if (std >= 157 && std <= 158) {
            pct = 16;
          } else if (std >= 159 && std <= 160) {
            pct = 17;
          } else if (std >= 161 && std <= 162) {
            pct = 18;
          } else if (std >= 163 && std <= 164) {
            pct = 19;
          } else if (std === 165) {
            pct = 20;
          } else if (std >= 166 && std <= 167) {
            pct = 21;
          } else if (std >= 168 && std <= 169) {
            pct = 22;
          } else if (std >= 170 && std <= 171) {
            pct = 23;
          } else if (std === 172) {
            pct = 24;
          } else if (std === 173) {
            pct = 25;
          } else if (std >= 174 && std <= 175) {
            pct = 26;
          } else if (std >= 176 && std <= 177) {
            pct = 27;
          } else if (std === 178) {
            pct = 28;
          } else if (std === 179) {
            pct = 29;
          } else if (std === 181) {
            pct = 30;
          } else if (std === 182) {
            pct = 31;
          } else if (std >= 183 && std <= 184) {
            pct = 32;
          } else if (std === 185) {
            pct = 33;
          } else if (std === 186) {
            pct = 34;
          } else if (std >= 187 && std <= 188) {
            pct = 35;
          } else if (std === 189) {
            pct = 36;
          } else if (std === 190) {
            pct = 37;
          } else if (std === 191) {
            pct = 38;
          } else if (std === 192) {
            pct = 39;
          } else if (std === 193) {
            pct = 40;
          } else if (std === 194) {
            pct = 41;
          } else if (std >= 195 && std <= 196) {
            pct = 42;
          } else if (std === 197) {
            pct = 43;
          } else if (std === 198) {
            pct = 44;
          } else if (std === 199) {
            pct = 45;
          } else if (std === 200) {
            pct = 46;
          } else if (std === 201) {
            pct = 47;
          } else if (std === 202) {
            pct = 48;
          } else if (std === 203) {
            pct = 49;
          } else if (std === 204) {
            pct = 50;
          } else if (std === 205) {
            pct = 51;
          } else if (std === 206) {
            pct = 52;
          } else if (std >= 207 && std <= 208) {
            pct = 53;
          } else if (std === 209) {
            pct = 54;
          } else if (std === 210) {
            pct = 55;
          } else if (std === 211) {
            pct = 56;
          } else if (std === 212) {
            pct = 57;
          } else if (std === 213) {
            pct = 58;
          } else if (std === 214) {
            pct = 60;
          } else if (std === 215) {
            pct = 61;
          } else if (std === 216) {
            pct = 62;
          } else if (std === 217) {
            pct = 63;
          } else if (std === 218) {
            pct = 64;
          } else if (std === 219) {
            pct = 65;
          } else if (std === 220) {
            pct = 66;
          } else if (std === 221) {
            pct = 67;
          } else if (std === 222) {
            pct = 68;
          } else if (std === 223) {
            pct = 69;
          } else if (std === 224) {
            pct = 70;
          } else if (std === 225) {
            pct = 71;
          } else if (std === 226) {
            pct = 72;
          } else if (std === 227) {
            pct = 73;
          } else if (std === 228) {
            pct = 74;
          } else if (std === 229) {
            pct = 75;
          } else if (std === 230) {
            pct = 76;
          } else if (std === 231) {
            pct = 77;
          } else if (std === 232) {
            pct = 78;
          } else if (std === 233) {
            pct = 79;
          } else if (std >= 234 && std <= 235) {
            pct = 80;
          } else if (std === 236) {
            pct = 81;
          } else if (std === 237) {
            pct = 82;
          } else if (std === 238) {
            pct = 83;
          } else if (std === 239) {
            pct = 84;
          } else if (std === 240) {
            pct = 85;
          } else if (std === 241) {
            pct = 86;
          } else if (std === 242) {
            pct = 87;
          } else if (std === 243) {
            pct = 88;
          } else if (std === 244) {
            pct = 89;
          } else if (std === 245) {
            pct = 90;
          } else if (std === 246) {
            pct = 91;
          } else if (std === 247) {
            pct = 92;
          } else if (std === 248) {
            pct = 93;
          } else if (std === 249) {
            pct = 94;
          } else if (std === 250) {
            pct = 95;
          } else if (std === 251) {
            pct = 96;
          } else if (std === 252) {
            pct = 97;
          } else if (std === 253) {
            pct = 98;
          } else if (std >= 254 && std <= 320) {
            pct = 99;
          } else {
            // Handle any other cases
          }
          // show number of correct answers out of total
          resultsContainer.innerHTML = `${numCorrect} out of ${myQuestions.length}`;
          categoryScoresContainer.innerHTML = `
          <p>
            <b>Screenshot this page and send it to your recruiter.</b>
            </p>
                <p>Your estimated AFQT score is ${pct}</p><br /><br />
                <p>Word Knowledge = ${scores.wk/2} out of 18</p>
                <p>Arithmetic Reasoning = ${scores.ar/2} out of 15</p>
                <p>Paragraph Comprehension = ${scores.pc/2} out of 8</p>
                <p>Mathmematics Knowledge = ${scores.mk/2} out of 13</p>`;

          // hide previous, next and submit button, and make quiz read-only
          const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
          const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
          const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
          previousButton.style.display = "none";
          nextButton.style.display = "none";
          submitButton.style.display = "none";

          const inputElements = quizContainer.querySelectorAll("input");
          inputElements.forEach(input => {
            input.setAttribute("disabled", true);


          });

          //add restart button
          const restartButton = document.getElementById("restart");
          restartButton.style.display = "block";
          restartButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            location.reload();
          });
        }

        function showSlide(n) {
          slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('active-slide');
          slides[n].classList.add('active-slide');
          currentSlide = n;
          if (currentSlide === 0) {
            previousButton.style.display = 'none';
          } else {
            previousButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
          }
          if (currentSlide === slides.length - 1) {
            nextButton.style.display = 'none';
            submitButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
          } else {
            nextButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
            submitButton.style.display = 'none';
          }
        }

        function showNextSlide() {
          showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
        }

        function showPreviousSlide() {
          showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
        }

        // Variables
        const quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
        const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
        const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
        const myQuestions = [{
            category: "wk",
            description: "<h2>PART I - WORD KNOWLEDGE. YOU WILL HAVE 7 MINUTES TO COMPLETE.</h2>",
            question: "1. <b><u>SMALL</u></b> MOST NEARLY MEANS?",
            answers: {
              a: "STURDY",
              b: "ROUND",
              c: "CHEAP",
              d: "LITTLE"
            },
            correctAnswer: "d"
          },
          {
            category: "ar",
            description: "<h2>PART II - ARITHMETIC REASONING - YOU WILL HAVE FOURTEEN (14) MINUTES:</h2>",
            question: "1. TWO AUTOMOBILES START TOGETHER FROM THE SAME PLACE AND TRAVEL ALONG THE SAME ROUTE. THE FIRST AVERAGES 40 MPH. THE SECOND 55 MPH. HOW MANY MILES FURTHER ALONG THE ROUTE IS THE SECOND AUTO AT THE END OF THE 5TH HOUR?",
            answers: {
              a: "55 x 5",
              b: "55 - 40",
              c: "(55x5) - (40x5)",
              d: "55/5 - 40/5"
            },
            correctAnswer: "c"
          },
          {
            category: "pc",
            description: "<h2>PART III - PARAGRAPH COMPREHENSION - YOU WILL HAVE SEVEN (7) MINUTES:</h2>",
            question: "1. THE DUTY OF THE LIGHTHOUSE KEEPER IS TO KEEP THE LIGHT BURNING NO MATTER WHAT HAPPENS, SO THAT SHIPS WILL BE WARNED OF THE PRESENCE OF DANGEROUS ROCKS. IF A SHIPWRECK SHOULD OCCUR NEAR THE LIGHTHOUSE, EVEN THOUGH HE WOULD LIKE TO AID IN THE RESCUE OF IT'S CREW AND PASSENGERS, THE LIGHTHOUSE KEEPER MUST......",
            answers: {
              a: "STAY AT HIS LIGHT",
              b: "RUSH TO THEIR AID",
              c: "TURN OUT THE LIGHT",
              d: "QUICKLY SOUND THE SIREN"
            },
            correctAnswer: "a"
          },
          {
            category: "mk",
            description: "<h2>PART IV - MATHEMATICS KNOWLEDGE - YOU WILL HAVE TWELVE (12) MINUTES:</h2>",
            question: "1. WHICH OF THE FOLLOWING IS THE SMALLEST PRIME NUMBER GREATER THAN 200?",
            answers: {
              a: "201",
              b: "205",
              c: "211",
              d: "214"
            },
            correctAnswer: "c"
          },
        ];

        // Kick things off
        buildQuiz();

        // Pagination
        const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
        const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
        const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
        let currentSlide = 0;
        let scores = {
          wk: 0,
          ar: 0,
          pc: 0,
          mk: 0,
        };

        // Show the first slide
        showSlide(currentSlide);

        // Event listeners
        submitButton.addEventListener('click', showResults);
        previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
        nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
      })();
    </script>
```

Comment: This does make the button work every time, but on the phone the button doesn't move down below the question/answer and it will overlap the text. The best way to describe the issue is if you change the margin-top on button to 0px you'll see it overlaps. Is there a way to get it lower without using a margin?

If I change .slide to relative the question jumps down the screen.

Comment: @Rob I changed the code and now it is at the bottom